# How handle resources in AngularJS 1.2 correctly?

Tags: angularjs

I updated my AngularJS from 1.0.7 to 1.2rc1 yesterday to check the new features. All works fine, but i run into some problems with ngResource. With these factory i get dummy data of a json file:

```
angular.module('RESTServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Customer', function($resource){
      return $resource(base+'customer.json', {}, {
        'query' : { method: 'GET', isArray: true, cache: caching }
      });
    });
```

I inject the RESTService in a controller and use it like:

```
Customer.query({}, function(response){
    $scope.customers = response;
  });
```

For one thing they are a array of customers in $scope.customers, for another thing they are to additional objects ($promise and $resolved) in the response. Screenshot of console show the resolve object.

[image]

And if i want to iterate over the response, the iterator walk all over the 200 customers and the $promise and $resolved object and i get errors because my code dont know how to handle these objects. In version 1.0.7 there was only 200 customers in the response.

**Did i something wrong? Must i check each item while iterating if is not $resolved or $response? Documentation is not clear about that in the moment.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the way how i iterate over the response.

I changed

```
for(item in items){
        for(attr in attributes){
          if(items[item][attributes[attr]].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString) != -1){
            matchedItems.push(items[item]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

to

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        for(attr in attributes){
          if(items[i][attributes[attr]].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterString) != -1){
            matchedItems.push(items[i]);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

and all works fine. AngularJS take care about the correct length value so i can use it for the for-loop instead of iteration over all values (including all values and $promise and $resolved) in the response.